# Is there a way to hide an if statement in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a thread that should be stopped if a button is pressed.

This means that for every action that I do, I also want to check if the stop flag is set so I can stop properly.

This is a piece of the code which should make it clearer:

```
while([self checkForDrop] != 0 && STOP == FALSE){
        sleep(0.4);
} if (STOP == TRUE){
        return 99;
}

ret = [self doSomething]
if(ret == 0){
    [self updateStatus] 
} else {
    printf("%d", ret) // Print error
} 

ret = [self doSomethingElse]
if(ret == 0){
    [self updateStatus] 
} else {
    printf("%d", ret) // Print error
} 

... and so on ...
```

Every time I do something, I want to also check if a condition is met `(STOP == TRUE)`, if it is, the program should return 99 and stop.

I could write an if statement for every line, but that would make the code unreadable and ugly. I would guess that I am not the only one that stumbled upon this, so there should be a better way.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the code you've posted in your question is being run on a background queue and not the main queue?

Comment: Yes. This is run in a thread with `@autoreleasepool`.